# Can we change Verb in Passive Voice

Tags: passive-voice

Can we change Verb tense in passive voice.

e.g.1

X killed Y. (Active Voice)

Y Killed by X (Passive Voice)

e.g.2

X died in the earthquake. (Active Voice)

X was killed in the earthquake. (passive Voice)

Can we change verb Died to killed in passive voice.

Also, I passive voice doer is either present or absent but from sentence we come to know that some has done to action.

But,

Was killed in accident.

Was killed in earthquake.

Was killed in landslide.

who is the doer in my above examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your two sentences are pretty well interchangeable.

In some contexts, they would not be nterchangeable, because "died" might be from disease or from old age, but "was killed" would not usually be used then. But "in the earthquake", the presumption is that the death was directly from the earthquake or its immediate consequences, and the two are interchangeable.

As for your last question: one of the main reasons that passives get used is that you do not have to specify the agent. You *can* do so (eg "He was killed in the earthqusake, by falling rubble"), but you do not have to. But in your examples, there probably wasn't a (human, or sentient) agent, and the proximate cause (eg falling rubble) may not be known.